# Signed APK will be re-compiled when running it with eclipse

Tags: android, adt

Now I'm using ADT18. I had been running singed APK on device by installing APK with eclipse before, with ADT15 or 16. But with ADT18, when I try to run (to install) signed APK, lovely eclipse re-compiles and overwrites signed (exported) APK.

Before I release APK on Google Play, I need to run it on my device. And I want to install it by running it with eclipse. I had been doing this practice over a year. But now I can't with ADT18 and I'm forced to install APK with different way.

How can I tell eclipse not to re-compile my signed APK and just install it and run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You *choose* where to export your signed apk and the version you run with Eclipse is signed with a debug key.

Comment: @CheJami, the issue is, I want to run my signed apk on device to see it works before releasing on market, but current ADT won't allow this. So I need to download my apk to device with another method which takes more steps to do.